# What data does InactivityMonitor of ActiveMQ see for checking connection availability?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I met the following exception yesterday.

> org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was
> inactive for too (>30000) long: tcp://127.0.0.1......

The exception was thrown while a queue session's commit method was being performed. I found out when the exception is thrown on the official website of activeMQ. It says:

> Connections are monitored by:
>
> - Ensuring **data** is read from the connection during the specified time period (Max Inactivity Duration).
> - Writing a **KeepAliveInfo message** to
>   the connection if no **normal activemq traffic** is sent across the
>   connection during the specified time period.

and

> Using the default values; if **no data** has been written or read from the
> connection for 30 seconds, the InactivityMonitor kicks in. The
> InactivityMonitor throws an InactivityIOException and shuts down the
> transport associated with the connection.

I understand what it says, I think. But I don't get what **data** is needed to be sent for InactivityIOException not to be thrown. I think the data does not mean normal queue massages.

**What is the data exactly?**

And in addtion, what does the following words mean??

- KeepAliveInfo message
- normal activemq traffic

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on the wire is any bytes traveling back and forth from client to broker.  The inactivity monitor tracks how long it's been since the last time some bytes have been sent or received, this can be any data, as it implies that the connection is not in a half closed state or the remote is hung etc.

Normally the regular flow of messages either to or from the broker will suffice to keep the connection active but when things get quiet the inactivity monitor starts to send KeepAliveInfo packets to the broker and the broker will respond in kind, this acts as a PING and PONG to ensure that the socket connection is still alive and well.

In your case it seems the client could not get any data back from the broker and it decided that the connection or broker must be faulty.  You'd need to investigate the logs of both broker and client to try and see what was happening around the time this happened.